# Sysinternals tool suite not working on low priv shell

Tags: windows, penetration-test, tools, metasploit, shellcode

Currently oscp student.  I asked this on the oscp forum yesterday, but no responses so far.  I am new to infosec, but have 18 years of education / work experience in IT.

As far as I can tell, microsoft sysinternals tools will not work if you have a low priv shell that can't write to HKCU\Software\Sysinternals in the registry.

Even if you pass the -accepteula option, it does not work. Anyone have any suggestions how to get the sysinternals suite to work in meterpreter with low priv shells?  I don't think it is possible.  Has Microsoft locked it down for low priv users?

I hope I am wrong because sysinternals are great tools.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it does not work?". Do you get an error message or does the app completely fail to run.

Comment: If you run any sysinternals command-line command it will just echo the command and do nothing.   accesschk users -cw * --accepteula

Comment: Don't most (maybe all) of the sysinternal tools access sensitive OS information? Why would you want them to work for a low-priv user?

Comment: Good question.  I want it to work for a low priv user because I am attacking the server (in a lab) not defending the server.  If access was denied.  I would expect the tool to say access denied or give some indication it is doing something.

Comment: The low priv user in my case could run ipconfig, netstat, net (some options), reg query, many things.  The user seemed to have lots of read, but no write access.

Comment: Upvotes are rare here huh?  At least my question didn't get closed as off topic :)